# How to make spring accept multiple synchronous requests?

Tags: java, spring, azure-web-app-service

I am implementing a system using Spring Boot 2.3.5 where two micro-services (e.g. A and B) make web requests to each other in a way like this:

**Service A** -> **Service B** -> **Service A**

This services are hosted in Azure App Services, where this type of flow works with no problem at all.

The problem is when running locally, the second call from **Service B** to **Service A** causes a *deadlock*, once the Service A is waiting for the service B to respond, causing a *timeout exception*.

My question is: Is there a way to make Spring Boot applications accept more than one request simultaneously while running on local machine?

I've already tried to set the variable `server.tomcat.threads.max` to 100 in the **application-local.yml** from the **Service A** but with no success.

Comment: Default number of threads is already 200 so you are actually decreasing the number of threads. There must be something else blocking that call, like a limited number of database connections.

Comment: Well pointed, I just figured out that the the Service A class which calls Service B is annotated with @Transactional, locking the connection to the database.

Comment: I took out the first call from the transactional method and now works like a charm, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out by M. Deinum the reason of the deadlock was a block in the database caused by the **@Transactional** annotation.

The problem was that during the second call to Service A the spring was trying to access a table which spring blocked because of the transactional.

What I did was take out the first call from the transactional method and place it in another use case, therefore when Service A tries to read the value, the table is already free.